# Using sapply() to determine frequency of correct response in R

Tags: r, sapply

I am using R to try to create a table of response frequencies for an assessment. I have two data frames: one with the assessment key, and one with student responses.

So far, I have created a new data frame with the count of each student response (a, b, c, etc.):

```
a_freq  <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "a")/length(q))
b_freq  <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "b")/length(q))
c_freq  <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "c")/length(q))
d_freq  <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "d")/length(q))
e_freq  <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "e")/length(q))
bl_freq <- sapply(responses, function(q) sum(q == "")/length(q))

response_freqs <- data.frame(rbind(a_freq, b_freq, c_freq, d_freq, e_freq, bl_freq))
colnames(response_freqs) <- responses_cols
rownames(response_freqs) <- c("a Freq", "b Freq", "c Freq", "d Freq", "e Freq", "Blank Freq")
```

`responses` is the data frame I am pulling from that contains a row per student and a question per column. Now, I am trying to figure out a way to use `sapply()` to iterate through the same data frame and pull the frequency for the correct response -- using a separate vector that contains the correct letter for each question.

I'm pretty new to R, and the `apply()` category of functions is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Interesting question. Please show us input data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how `responses` looks like, but assuming that it looks like

```
responses<-data.frame(question1=c("a","b","c","a"),question2=c("a","a","c","c"))
```

i.e.

```
  question1 question2
1         a         a
2         b         a
3         c         c
4         a         c
```

and suppose that the correct answers to question1 and question2 are `correctAnswers=c("b","c")`
then you could define the following function

```
frequencyCounter<-function(indexColumn){
    frequencyCorrectResponses<-sum(responses[,indexColumn]==correctAnswers[indexColumn])
    return(frequencyCorrectResponses)
}
```

and then `sapply(c(1,2),frequencyCounter)` which yields

```
[1] 1 2
```

because for `question1` there is only one correct answer `"b"`, and for `question2` there are 2 correct answers `"c"`

---

EDIT SHORTER VERSION:

```
sapply(c(1,2),function(indexColumn) sum(responses[,indexColumn]==correctAnswers[indexColumn]))
```

which yields

```
[1] 1 2
```